# Outbound SPF Record and DKIM Keys

Tags: email, dkim

We have a client who's blocking emails sent from salesforce under their email domain like @domain.org. The emails will be blocked if they don't have active SPF records and DKIM keys. Currently the org does not have a DKIM associated with their domain, nor an SPF record as far as I am able to tell. If I generate both of these and pass them to the client, will that allow emails to pass through the block? Or do I need to do something further in order to ensure emails are sent with the specific DKIM key / SPF Record? Any help is very appreciated as I'm not very familiar with these keys and such, thanks!

Comment: Typically SPF and DKIM keys are added to domain in question. For ex., if your domain is companya.com, your company DNS admin will add these dns records (usually TXT) to your DNS system. It needs to be added based on the configuration identified by email sending system. With that said, have you checked out this FAQ? https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000354353&type=1

Comment: I had checked the FAQ, and I think I mostly understand it. So if I were to generate a DKIM key with the org's domain, and then pass along it's CNAME to that company for registration in their DNS then they shouldn't have any issues?

Comment: Hi thanks, like I said from the previous comment I've read the FAQ and am just trying to confirm my understanding of it